# facebook OAuth with application issue

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I have done login with facebook account.

Everything is okay, but problem is that when i have created "app1"  it is fine for accessing the first name and email perfectly but not for the other application "app2" .

Both "app1" and "app2" created on facebook.

Do i need to setup anything special for application to fetch email of users.

Why it works fine for "app1" but not for "app2".

my code is very simple (Javscript and jquery given on facebook) code is not an issue. only the problem is why one application is able to get email while other is not.

Do i need to do any setting for application on facebook?

my sample code is.......

FB.login(function (response) {

```
            if (response.session) {

                var url = '/me?fields=name,email';

                FB.api(url, function (response) {

                    var image = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture';

                    alert(response.name);
                    alert(response.email);

                   .....
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you get the access token and how you retrieve it? Different application will need different access token....

Comment: access token is itself maintain by facebook, we don't need to worry about it, i gues